# Issue with ggplot2 presenting map

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I've been trying to work with a data.frame and a shapefile I've been using the below code:

```
    Jul_Col_map <- 
    ggplot(data = Jul_Data, aes(x = Long_DD, y = Lat_DD, color = Coliform)) + 
    geom_point(size = 4) +
    geom_sf(aes(Cave_initial), size = 1) +
    scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +
    labs(x = "",
    y = "",
    color = "Coliform (cfu/100mL)") +
    guides(color = guide_colourbar(barwidth = 0.5, barheight = 10)) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 12), axis.text.y = 
    element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 12), axis.title.x = element_text(face = 
    "bold", color = "black", size = 16), axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", 
    size = 16))  

    Jul_Col_map
```

But I always get the error

```
    Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Long_DD' not found
```

I have properly uploaded the data set and converted it to a sf using st_as_sf and when I run selected code everything works fine until I actually want to show the map.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is there a column ```Long_DD``` in your ```Jul_Data```? If you could add result of ```head(Jul_Data)```or if you could share a subset with ```dput(...)``` it would help reproducing the error.

Comment: So I after using the transformation st_as_sf it transformed my numerical coordinates into a geometry tab. With all the coordinates represented as c(-90.1389, 38.2344)